# Cakephp Fixture with different table name and in a plugin

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, fixtures

I'm new to testing with CakePHP and now that was creating a new plugin wanted to create the unit tests for it.

The new plugin 'MyPlugin' connects to multiple databases where one is shared with an none cake application(migrating to cake) that does not follow the cake naming standards.

The first test I wanted to create was getting some data from the 'AppApiKey' table - but the name in the database is all lower case without the '_', so 'appapikey' instead of 'app_api_key'.

Created a Fixture in the plugin called 'AppApiKeyFixture'

```
namespace MyPlugin\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class AppApiKeyFixture extends TestFixture {
    public $connection = 'test_ctrller';
    public $table = 'appapikey';

    //public $import = [ 'table' => 'appapikey', 'connection' => 'ctrller' ];
    public $fields = [
        'id' => ['type' => 'string'],
        'key' => ['type' => 'string' ],
        'label' => 'text',
        'creationdstamp' => 'datetime',
        '_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id']]
        ]
    ];

    public $records = [ 
        [
            'id' => '03380d5b-1b05-467a-af32-ca8aecb4dcc6',
            'key' => '53b4359a-a7d9-d6d7-9853-e569f408eae9',
            'label' => 'MyLabel',
            'creationdstamp' => '2019-11-12 15:53:48.176576+00'
        ] 
    ];
}
```

I've been trying a few things, it seems a describe will always be done no matter if you're using the import or not (so why does $fields exist?)

Filled in the '$fields' and '$records'. As far as I understood from the docs and experienced:

1. a describe is done using the original connection
2. a table 'test_xxx' table is created and filled in the 'test'/'test_xxx' connection
3. test is run on the table (+ $records data) on the test(_xxx) connection

But the above fixture gives me

> Cake\Database\Exception: Cannot describe app_api_key. It has 0 columns.

Does it need a '$table = xxx' somewhere else?, don't see it in the docs.

This keeps happening no matter what is filled in for '$table' or '$import'

In the app itself this table class works:

```
namespace MyPlugin\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class AppApiKeyTable extends Table { 
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('appapikey');
    }

    public static function defaultConnectionName() {
        return 'ctrller';
    }
}
```

The TestCase calls this function that I want tested:

```
namespace MyPlugin\Auth\ApiKey;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ApiKeyAuthenticator {
    public function getApiKeyInfo($pKey) {
        return TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('AppApiKey')->findByKey($pKey)->first();
    }
}
```

Additionally found it strange that in another Fixture I had to use the '$import' and that without it I also get a:

> Cake\Database\Exception: Cannot describe softwareid. It has 0 columns

The Fixture is:

```
namespace MyPlugin\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class SoftwareidFixture extends TestFixture {
    //public $import = [ 'table' => 'softwareid', 'connection' => 'default' ];
    public $fields = [
        'id' => ['type' => 'string'],
        'softwareid' => ['type' => 'string' ],
        'name' => 'text',
        'created' => 'datetime',
        '_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id']]
        ]
    ];

    public $records = [ 
        [
            'id' => '5e26b612-2b74-40ed-aaa5-b48cb4b1d946',
            'softwareid' => '228ebfe2-4a2b-49ec-ab75-43f44007b68d',
            'name' => 'MySoftwarePackage',
            'created' => '2019-10-31 12:08:10+00'
        ] 
    ];
}
```

The above is a table in the default connection, the '$fields' and '$records' should be enough right?, no need to define the '$import'

Answer (score 0):

So got it working for both tables with the import, in my case this is a good fix due to once the migration complete (long term project) there will be 70 to 100 tables

The easy way was to define the model, it was in the docs but was staring myself blind on the '$table', '$connection' and '$fields' that are mentioned in the docs.

So the fixture ended in:

```
namespace MyPlugin\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class AppApiKeyFixture extends TestFixture {
    public $import = [ 'model' => 'AppApiKey', 'connection' => 'ctrller' ];
    public $records = [ 
        [
            'id' => '03380d5b-1b05-467a-af32-ca8aecb4dcc6',
            'key' => '53b4359a-a7d9-d6d7-9853-e569f408eae9',
            'label' => 'MyLabel',
            'creationdstamp' => '2019-11-12 15:53:48.176576+00'
        ] 
    ];
}
```

For anyone having issues with getting the unittests working with different table names and connections, referencing the model seems to be the way to go.